# C++ Union , Intersection , Difference

Tags: c++, set, difference

So I'm working on a code to find the Union, Intersection and Difference between two arrays. I'm done with the Union and Intersection but i just can't figure out the difference(A - B) ,For example A={1,3,6,9,7,9} , B={2,3,-2,9} i want to get A - B = { 1,6,7,0} .

I don't want to use any other library except iostream.

This is my code so far.

```
/* Prints union of A[] and B[]
   SizeA is the number of elements in A[]
   SizeB is the number of elements in B[] */

cout << "\nUnion of A and B = "; //
i = 0; j = 0;
while (i < SizeA && j < SizeB)
{
    if (A[i] < B[j])
        cout << A[i++] << " ";

    else if (B[j] < A[i])
        cout << B[j++] << " ";

    else
    {
        cout << B[j++] << " ";
        i++;
    }
}
/* Print remaining elements of the larger array */
while (i < SizeA)
    cout << A[i++] << " ";

while (j < SizeB)
    cout << B[j++] << " ";



cout << "\nIntersection of A and B = ";
for (i = 0; i < SizeA; i++) //for loop to calculate the intersection of A and B.
{
    for (j = 0; j < SizeB; j++)
    {
        if (A[i] == B[j])
        {
            cout << A[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested these with for example `A = { 1,20 } B = { 2,3,4,5,6 }` and `A = { 1,5,6 } B = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 }` ?

Comment: So of the three things you mention - you've done two, and are only really asking about the third? Can you show any pseudocode, thinking or research? Did you try something? Can you describe what the set difference is in your own words?

Comment: Ye this is not the full code , the union and Intersection work without any bugs im just stuck with the difference , for example if A={1,3,6,9,7,9} , B={2,3,-2,9} i want to get A - B = { 1,6,7,0}

Comment: Are you assuming that the arrays are sorted?

Comment: What i have done so far is make the user enter the array size and its elements and then i wrote the Union and inIntersection code nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very bad practice because it's not general, not using a clean function and using plain old arrays but I assumed that you are beginner and have to do it in this way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int A [] ={1,3,6,9,7}, Asz =  5, B [] ={2,3,-2,9}, Bsz =  4;
    std::cout << "\nThe difference is {";
    for( int i = 0; i < Asz; ++i){
        int temp = A[i];
        bool notFound = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < Bsz; ++j){
            if(temp == B[j]) notFound = false;
        }
        if(notFound)
        {
            if(i < Asz - 1) std::cout << temp << ", ";
            else std::cout << temp ;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "}";
}
```

The way I prefer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> A = {1,3,6,9,7, 0} , B={2,3,-2,9}, C;

    std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    std::sort(B.begin(), B.end());

    std::set_difference(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), B.cbegin(), B.cend(), std::back_inserter(C), std::less<int>{});

    for(auto const & el : C)
        std::cout << el << ", ";
}
```

Comment: Yes sir i'm actually at the second semester for my CS degree

Comment: Aren't you missing the elements that are in B, but not in A?

Comment: Thiss i exactly what i was looking for ! Thanks :)

Comment: @melk this is `A-B` while what U R taking about is `A ^ B` (intersection)

Comment: Regarding your stdlib implementation: first, set_difference requires a sorted range, so you have to apply std::sort first. Second, prefer a std::vector over a std::list (use cases for std::list are rare).

Comment: @davidhigh I think `list` here is better

Comment: I don't. Look [here](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list.html), section "sort". A list performs much worse than a vector. Second, when it comes to back-insertion, a vector is also more performant.

Comment: Thanks for adjusting, and +1

Answer (score 0):

If you could save the intersection, you could then just check each element of A and B against the elements of the intersection. Otherwise, you need two for-loops:

```
cout << "\nDifference of A and B = ";
for (i = 0; i < SizeA; i++) //for loop to calculate the intersection of A and B.
{
    bool found = false
    for (j = 0; j < SizeB; j++)
    {
        if (A[i] == B[j])
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
       cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < SizeB; i++)
{
    bool found = false
    for (j = 0; j < SizeA; j++)
    {
        if (B[i] == A[j])
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
       cout<<B[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Edit: Never mind, i got the definition of difference wrong (thought it was (A-B) + (B-A)), so only the first for-loop is needed, and there's no point saving the intersection.

Comment: U mean create a third array C for example and save the intersection?

Comment: @Pneuma Yes, you could do that, but memory-management on that array would be a bit annoying (you'd have to allocate the size of the bigger of the two arrays, probably wasting some memory, and then keep track of how many items it contains). Using std::vector would be better, but that'd mean including an extra header (<vector>), which you don't want.

Comment: We still havent learnt vector in my uni :( , there are just so many things to learn it's exausting even thinking about it